# How to instantiate an ILoggerFactory without using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have an existing class that needs a parameterless constructor.  I want to log an error and some other data from within it.  Everywhere else in my app I put the `ILoggerFactory` in my constructor and DI takes care of it and thus I can log and such.  I can not do that in this case because of the requirement of the parameterless constructor.

Can I create a instance of the `ILoggerFactory` or any other class I have put into the Dependency Injection stream from my Startup class?

Comment: For situations like this you should register a factory class for your existing class. Have it construct the class then set a public property or call a public method to inject the ILogger.

Comment: How do you use the class? Can you define a public property for the ILoggerFactory? And set this property from outside the class?

Comment: @Nikolaus I plan to rewrite the class to not be so self-contained and can `get` an `ILoggerFactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Configure (in Startup.cs) you get IApplicationBuilder passed in, which has an ApplicationServices property (IServiceProvider).

You can easily do something like

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    GetMeSomeServiceLocator.Instance = app.ApplicationServices;
}

public static class GetMeSomeServiceLocator
{
    public static IServiceProvider Instance { get; set; }
}
```

and then later, somewhere totally unrelated, do

```
public void SomeRandomMethod()
{
    var service = GetMeSomeServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<MyAwesomeService>();

    // Do something with service
}
```

It's a horrible anti-pattern, and you should never do this, though.

Shamelessly stolen from https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/294 (so that it would be here for posterity).

Comment: I implemented what you asked and am calling it like: `var lf = ServiceInstantiator.Instance.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();` but getting the error `The non-generic method IServiceProvider.GetService(Type) cannot be used with type arguments`.  However, this `var lf = ServiceInstantiator.Instance.GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory))` compiles but I cannot then do: `lf.CreateLogger<MyClass>();`

Comment: @Grandizer you have to add `as ILoggerFactory` before `;`

Comment: It's probably a case of missing using statement, the GetService<> methods are actually extension methods.

Comment: P.S.  the namespace is Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Answer (score 0):

Autofac supports *property Injection* which allows you to inject a Logger after the object has been resolved from the container. It's configured using `.PropertiesAutowired` in the  builder code.